# Radiofrequency acceleration of ions in a collider

Tags: experimental-physics, particle-accelerators

Reading about the radiofrequency acceleration in circular colliders (https://home.cern/about/engineering/radiofrequency-cavities) made me wonder, this is how it is performed for particles going in one direction, but at the same time the particles going on the other direction need to be accelerated. Are the beams synchronized in order for one of them to be inside the cylindrical electrodes while the one running in the opposite direction is crossing the cavity and being accelerated?

What about for linear colliders? Is the acceleration performed on the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particles going in each direction are in separate beamlines. They both have their own set of RF cavities, as well as dipole and quadrupole magnets.

This needs to be the case, since both beams contain positively charged particles, so they need an opposite direction magnetic field to stay in the beam lines. Since this forces them to be in separate beamlines, they can't share RF cavities.

Linear colliders are the same way (usually, at least), since you need to have two separate beamlines if you want to collide them at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If they are in separate beamlines, how are they make to collide?

Comment: @Juanjo There are four places where the beams switch beamlines, and so the beams cross. The four large experiments (CMS, ATLAS, LHCb, and ALICE) are each placed at one of these interaction points.